# JAXB marshaling. How to retrieve the binding name for a dynamically bind field

Tags: dynamic, jaxb, bind, marshalling

This post intented to be a question but during its composition i figured out a solution and i would like to share it.

I have a jax-ws web service with one operation that takes only one parameter, lets say it is called AnimalParameter. The thing is that the client can invoke my service with any animal he likes (one at a time). The animals are predefined though.
My purpose is to retrieve the contents of this "AnicmalParameter" and invoke another web service service that actually has one operation per animal.

I used the XmlElements in combination with inheritance as  a dynamic binding choise in order to catch every animal with the same bean:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class AnimalParameter implements Serializable {

    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "dog", type=Dog.class ),
            @XmlElement(name = "cat", type=Cat.class )
    })
    protected Animal animal;    
 }
```

In my case the client will invoke with one animal at a time. So the xml will be like:

```
<animalParameter>
  <dog>
    ...
  </dog>
</animalParameter>
```

or :

```
<animalParameter>
  <cat>
    ...
  </cat>
</animalParameter>
```

It is fairly easy to marshal the whole animal container into a string by doing:

```
final Writer xmlString = new StringWriter();
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AnimalParameter.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(animalParameter, xmlString);
```

My problem here was that i wanted to print an xml only with the animal (dog or cat not the whole parameter) i received and this seems very difficult as in compile time i do not know the animal that my web service is going to be invoked with. So even my bean above is able to bind requests with dog and cat how can you marshal it as xml without the root element. I tried to put a convenience method in my bean:

```
 @XmlRootElement
    public class AnimalParameter implements Serializable 
        .
        .
        .   
        @XmlElement
        public Animal   getAnimal(){
                return animal;
        }
}
```

and to use:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Animal.class);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(animalParameter.getAnimal(), xmlString);
```

The xml printed is :

```
<animal>...</animal> and not the desired <cat>...</cat> or <dog>...</dog>
```

My understanding here is that the binding metadata that JAXB uses in order to bind the xml to the java class/fields is not stored anywhere it is just runtime executed code. So the java field "animal" really does not have a clue to which xml node it really was bind to.

I solved using this:

```
String animalName = animalParameter.getAnimal().getClass().getSimpleName();
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Animal.class);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<Operation>(new QName(animalName), Animal.class, animalParameter.getAnimal()), stringWriter);
```